# Show div as per a pre selected dropdown when page loads

Tags: jquery-ui, show-hide

I want to show a division as per the selected value in drop down list when page loads. For example,

If I have a drop down containing 2 options and i have selected option 2 and it shows a div2 then when page reloads, it should again show the option2 selected and div2 shown instead of option1 and its div1.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve